# drop cassandra primary key index

Tags: database-design, cassandra, nosql

Since Cassandra indexes primary keys by default, it is known that it does not support dropping the index on the primary key. But is it possible to actually do that by modifying the cassandra source code?

Answer (score 1):

In Cassandra there is no such thing as index on primary key - the primary key defines the path how the data is stored in Cassandra and read from it.

P.S. You can think of Cassandra as nested hash tables - partition key is the first level of the keys that defines on which machine the data is located, then each clustering column narrows down the data sets until the last clustering column points to actual columns with data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To maintain integrity, the primary key has to be mandatorily specified while creating a cassandra column family. Once the column family is created, the primary key gets indexed by default as per the cassandra documentation. My question is about how to restrain/prevent the creation of the primary index.

Comment: There is no such thing as primary index. The key is defining the physical location of the data. I recommend to check DSE Architecture guide: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-arch/index.html